# Where I can find the Windows build of wget 1.13.4?

Tags: windows, wget

I can't seem to find the latest version of wget easily using a Google Search. I'm looking for a Windows version that I can use, and no one seems to have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find a windows, working, compile of [wget 1.13.4](http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2010/05/wget-112-for-windows.html) here, they also seem to keep up to date windows compiles of popular GNU/Linux soft ware on this site.